# How can I resolve this ModuleNotFoundError while the module is installed and only in debug mode?

Tags: python, pip, python-module, python-packaging, modulenotfounderror

Whenever I run my program in debug mode the module is not found even though the module is correctly installed and imported.
I state that I have this problem also with other modules that I import. I started by installing the module using:

```
pip install 2captcha-python
```

After installing it I checked that it was in my pip list, here is the list:

```
 C:\Users\matt>pip list
Package                   Version
------------------------- ---------
2captcha-python           1.1.2
altgraph                  0.17.2
certifi                   2022.6.15
charset-normalizer        2.1.1
future                    0.18.2
idna                      3.3
pefile                    2022.5.30
pip                       22.2.2
pyarmor                   7.6.1
pyinstaller               5.3
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2022.10
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0
setuptools                65.3.0
urllib3                   1.26.12
wheel                     0.37.1
```

I also checked in my path **c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages** and this is the list:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3I9j.png)

I checked that in the twocaptcha folder there was the file

```
__init__.py
```

and it was correctly present and written, here the code:

```
from .api import ApiClient
from .solver import (TwoCaptcha, SolverExceptions, ValidationException,
                     NetworkException, ApiException, TimeoutException)

__version__ = '1.1.2'
```

in my python script I imported the module as follows:

```
import os
import requests
import re
import sys
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha

#start...
```

**NOTE:**
when I run the program normally the script works correctly and does not give any problems, but when I run the debug this error is generated:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\matt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\matt\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\matt\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\matt\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "c:\Users\matt\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path        
    return matt(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "c:\Users\matt\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "c:\Users\matt\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code       
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\matt\Desktop\geo\geo.py", line 5, in <module>
    from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twocaptcha'
```

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohkBZ.png)

How can I fix this Module not found error while the module is installed? **Error that occurs only when running in debug**

Answer (score 0):

I installed it this way:

```
pip install twocaptcha
```

It imports just fine this way.

Comment: it didn't work, keep giving me the same error

Comment: Have you tried using virtualenv?